# how can i get rid of this attribute error?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

i am learning OOP in python and i was trying to import some classes and then print a function of this class, but i get an 'attribute error' everysingle time i run it.

this is the file 1 code:

```
import  file_inheritanceB

usuario1 = file_inheritanceB.FreeUser(2248500, 'erickkpruneda', 'erick', 'pruneda')
```

this is the file 2 code:

```
class FreeUser: # superclase
    user_cat = 'Free'
    advertising = True

    def __init__(self, id, username, name, lastname):
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname

    def showData(self):
        print('id: ' + self.id)
        print('username: ' + self.username)
        print('name: ' + self.name)
        print('tipo de suscripción: ' + FreeUser.user_cat)
```

and i get this:
File "/Users/erickpruneda/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Air de Erick/developer/python OOP/file_inheritanceA.py", line 3, in 
usuario1 = file_inheritanceB.FreeUser(2248500, 'erickkpruneda', 'erick', 'pruneda')
AttributeError: module 'file_inheritanceB' has no attribute 'FreeUser'

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking at the wrong file.

Comment: is file 2 named file_inheritanceB ?